# some methods working on linux not on mac on same version of chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am building a chrome extension in which to close the popup window I am using `window.close()` and `self.close()` and both of them are working in Google Chrome for Kali Linux but not in Google Chrome for Mac where both of the google chrome versions are same being 35.0.
Same is the case with `chrome.runtime.reload()`. It works on chrome linux but not on chrome for mac.
Suggest some reliable methods to close the popup window and reload the same extension. I dont want to use management permission to do the same.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds like bugs. You probably should file that at [crbug](https://crbug.com)